# c++, MingW, undefined reference to `libiconv'

Tags: c++, mingw, libiconv

I'm getting these errors with MingW:

```
undefined reference to `libiconv_close'
undefined reference to `libiconv_open'
undefined reference to `libiconv'
```

I have the libiconv package from MingW installed. What is causing this? If this is of some importance, I'm trying to get [tinygettext](http://code.google.com/p/tinygettext) working.

Comment: show us the commands you are using to build your app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must have forgotten to add -liconv to the link line.  Adding that there should resolve those problems.